# multisearch API via curl

Tags: elasticsearch

I've been looking at the documentation for multisearch API with the objective of exporting specific values of a field in Elasticsearch for a given time period.

I still haven't figured out a way of getting all the results of `fieldA` for the past `24h` while applying a filter of `filter: KEY`

Is this possible to do via curl request to the Elasticsearch endpoint? Running 7.7.0.

Comment: can you add an example

Comment: fieldA holds A, B, C, D, E, F and many more. I'd like to get all values of fieldA for the last 24h while making sure to apply filter: KEY so that only values in that condition are given. I don't have an example to provide, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can use term query to filter on values and a range query to get values more than a date.

[Terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) will give all values for a field. If you just need documents you can skip this part.

**Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {                                 --> to filer on a value
          "term": {
            "fieldA.keyword": "A"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {   
            "timestamp": {
              "gte": "now-24h/h"          --> within 24 hr from now
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": { 
    "fieldA": {
      "terms": {                                    --> term aggregation
        "field": "fieldA.keyword",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Result:**

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "index57",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "Uf4aOnIBRc7WtBUiRs6e",
        "_score" : 0.0,
        "_source" : {
          "timestamp" : "2020-05-21",
          "fieldA" : "A"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "fieldA" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "A",
          "doc_count" : 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: How can it be run from curl? Does size: 10 limit the output results to just 10? I'd like to download all (possible thousands) results.

Comment: @t988GF you can increase the size value  to suit your requirement. For curl  use curl -XPOST "https://localhost:9200/index-name/_search" -d'
 Followed by query

Comment: TY! Can I run it without a limit, so that it shows ALL records for the full 24h period?

Comment: @t988GF Size has to be given . For aggregation part you can use composite aggregation to paginate the data